# Typed class with user-extensible type parameter in C++

Tags: c++, enums, shared-libraries

Suppose you’re writing a library, providing a class with some kind of “type” parameter. For this one might use an enum:

```
namespace MyLib {
  class Event {
  public:
    enum EventType { TYPE1, TYPE2, ... };
    Event(EventType _type) : type(_type) { }
  private:
    EventType type;
  }
}
```

Then to instantiate:

```
new MyLib::Event(Event::TYPE1);
```

Fine so far. But what if you want the user to be able to extend the list of event types? This is not possible if the type property is an enum.

Low-quality possibilities include asking them to `#define` custom event names, or simply using strings, though those both seem suboptimal.

Is there a general solution to this?

One suggestion has been to use a `struct EventType` to return values within a specified range in an enum. However, while this solves the compiler-safety issue, it doesn’t address the problem of adding *named* types – it would require the user to add these to the global scope.

One possibility which addresses the latter but not the former issue is to typedef EventType to an integral type, and leave it to the user to add custom types to the library’s namespace or their own. A factory method to provide unique values could be provided as part of Event:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace MyLib {

  namespace EventType {
    typedef int T;
    enum { TYPE1, TYPE2, Count};
  }

  class Event {
  public:
    Event(EventType::T _type) : type(_type) { }
    EventType::T type;
    static EventType::T registerType() { return _typeid++; }
  private:
    static int _typeid;
  };

}

MyLib::EventType::T MyLib::Event::_typeid = EventType::Count;

// The user can then add types, including to the library's namespace
// (which may or may not be a good idea)
namespace MyLib { namespace EventType {
  MyLib::EventType::T MYTYPE = MyLib::Event::registerType();
} }

int main() {
  MyLib::Event ev1(MyLib::EventType::TYPE2);
  MyLib::Event ev2(MyLib::EventType::MYTYPE);
  std::cout << ev1.type << std::endl;
  std::cout << ev2.type << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
```

While this doesn’t technically restrict the parameter to a registered set of types, the typedef & namespacing provides a helpful syntactic cue in the constructor definition and auto-suggestion in IDEs, and it prevents user types from having to pollute the global scope, which is perhaps the greater concern.

Is there a better way to specify a finite, compiler-checked but user-extensible set of values as a type parameter to a class, or generally to a function/method?

Comment: How would the library's code know what to do with the new extended values? And as an aside to avoid using reserved names it's safest to just avoid leading underscores.

Comment: Who says that enums are not extensible? You can use any value from the underlying integral type.

Comment: What is the problem that you are actually trying to solve that would require this? I believe there can be different approaches that will better suit the problem than using enums, but at the same time, without context any alternative offered can be completely absurd and irrelevant to your real problem.

Comment: Rob, the problem with enums is they’re not extensible _qua_ enums: there’s no easy way to ask the user to extend the enum with a set of new values. David, the problem is exactly the second example – an Event class with a “type” property with several default values, but which the user should be able to extend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to simply take the event type as a normal integral type, use an enumeration to define the built-in types, and provide user-defined min and max values between which the user creates their own integer values with a separate enumerator. Then you'll just use assertion to make sure that the base event doesn't try to process an unknown event type.

EDIT: Do note that a base event class with some types that understands and some that it doesn't may be fragile, unless it's just holding the data for the child class to pick out again later. Even in that case it might be better to consider an alternate design. Can you elaborate on how the event type is *used* after it's set?

EDIT2: I think I understand better now, the event stores the event type and an event consumer can retrieve that from the event. If the consumer understands the extended event type it can do appropriate processing, else delegate, assert, or simply no-op. Given that, I think using an integral event type seems fine.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that sounds like an interesting solution. I had considered an integer type, perhaps with a static method of Event to provide a unique integer value: `EventType my_event_type = Event::registerEventType();`; using an assertion with this would seem like a fairly decent solution. Re: your Q, I’m not sure I fully understand it – what different types are you referring to? – but Event is not intended to be subclassed.

Comment: @BenjiXVI I did exactly that as a solution for this problem recently. The registration method works with a simple int parameter, the enums are organized in reserved ranges. My problem was to describe a generic EEPROM (think file) layout for component specific constants. I have a standard constant set, component specific constants sets and want to allow user specific constant sets. The 'constant names' are specified using enums and a registry takes these + information which type and adress offset in the concrete device's EEPROM should be used.

Comment: Hi g-makulik, do you mean you did as per the example from the newly-edited Q? If you did something else I’d be very interested to see that written up as an answer..!

Answer (score 0):

I'd extend the space of my enumerated type, like so:

```
/* UNTESTED */
struct MyType {
 enum e { type1, type2, type3, max_type = type3, _big = max_type+256 };

 /** Acceptable values are 0-255 */
 static e UserType(int i) { return e(max_type + 1 + i); }
};

void f (MyType::e t) {}

int main () {
  f(MyType::type1);
  f(MyType::UserType(47));
  enum UserEnum { utype1, utype2, utype3 };
  f(MyType::UserType(utype3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with enum, but you can define a new type.

the c++ enum is about the same as a class:

```
struct Enum
{
  int value;
  explicit Enum(int v) : value(v) {}
  operator int () {return value;}
};

static const Enum value_1 = Enum(1);
static const Enum value_2 = Enum(2);
...
```

Well it's not exactly the same, there are a few differences, like you can't inherit from an enum, and enums are integer types, so you can cast int to enums, but these are not big differences.

if you do it like this, then you can add new values to the "enum" by simply adding new constants.

```
static const Enum custom_value_1 = Enum(100);
static const Enum custom_value_2 = Enum(200);
```

You need to make them `static`, because C++ is stupid, and allocates resources even though they could be used as compile time constants. An alternative to `static`, is to place them into an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace
{
  const Enum custom_value_1 = Enum(100);
  const Enum custom_value_2 = Enum(200);
}
```

If you don't do one of these you'll get linker errors. This method will provide you with the same type of type-checking enums get, and you can extend the values, in separate header files.